# How to override AbstractMethod Capture function Magento 2

Tags: magento2, sales-order, plugin

I need to update **amount** in **capture** function of abstract method. For this I have created a **plugin**.

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\MyModule\Model\Plugin;

class OrderCapture extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod
{        
    public function capture(\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment, $amount)
    {
        print_r($payment);
        exit;    
    }

}
```

It is **not reflecting** any changes when I **place an order**.

Please do suggest

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        /**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\MyModule\Model\Plugin;
use Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface;
use Magento\Payment\Model\MethodInterface;
use Magento\Authorizenet\Model\Directpost;

class OrderCapture
{
    public function beforeCapture(Directpost $subject, $result,InfoInterface $payment,$amount)
    {
        print_r($payment);
        exit;

    }

}
```

And XML will be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Authorizenet\Model\Directpost">
        <plugin name="order_order_capture" type="Vendor\MyModule\Model\Plugin\OrderCapture" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: No its not working. I want to update amount beforeCapture. I am using authorize.net payment method.

Comment: you can do that with `beforeCapture`

Comment: I did. But no luck. Nothing will be print

Comment: I looked into this. This payment method is using directPost.php  initialize function. How do i override capture amount of all payment method in my custom module?

Comment: I have updated answer

Comment: You did particularly for authorizenet. I want to override for all the online payment method

Comment: I am still waiting for your response.